# Insert HTML Code Just After the Opening BODY Tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, html-injections

Does anyone have any samples of injecting a HTML snippet just after the open BODY tag in an ASP.Net webforms page?  The positioning of this code is very specific.

The beginning HTML might look like this:

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
```

The resulting HTML should look like this:

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="new-div"></div>
<div id="header">
```

This is a scenario where the HTML cannot be manipulated directly, and javascript would do this too late for the additional HTML to be useful.  It must be done with server-side code and in place before the HTML makes it to the web browser.

Comment: Would it make sense to do this with Javascript?

Comment: Sorry... This needs to be done with server side code, if possible. Needs to be loaded before the page is rendered. More specifically, before the mark-up is received by the web browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way in your aspx markup:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= FunctionTheOutputsString() %>
```

The `<%=` is short for `Response.Write()`, which is a function that writes directly into the page.

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more specific.  The body tag and the HTML is only accessible via server-side code for this project.

Comment: In the mark-up. My project doesn't give you access to that. This needs to be done in server side code, outside of the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can use `prepend()` as so:

```
​$(function(){
 $('body').prepend('<div id="new-div">Div content</div>');
})​;
```

[​jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/3yhsm/)

**Update**: The server-side solution could also be (besides above answer):

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
   <asp:placeholder id="divPlaceHolder" Visible="False" runat="server">
      <div id="new-div">
      </div>
   </asp:placeHolder>
```

On Page_Load()...

```
 if(SomeCondition)
    divPlaceHolder.Visible=true;
```

And because non-visible elements aren't rendered, the `new-div` element will only be displayed if `SomeCondition` is true

Comment: _"It must be done with server-side code and in place before the HTML makes it to the web browser."_

Comment: @canon Actually, the OP edited the question. When I read it initially, it didn't have the server-side restriction. Anyway, I have provided both solutions.

Comment: I also have no power to add the placeholder.  This must be strictly server side.